# How to update the sharedpreferences from recyclerview adapter class class when a recyclerview card is removed in Main class?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I have a main class that is responsible for adding cards to recycler view and saving the card name in shared preferences. But when I am deleting a card then how can I update the same in shared preferences? Since the card deletion is done is the recyclerview adapter class only?

Main class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lighting);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        ahomeLayout = findViewById(R.id.lay4);
        buttonScan1 = findViewById(R.id.buttonscan1);
        buttonScan2 = findViewById(R.id.fab1);
        buttonScan3 = findViewById(R.id.fab2);

        mRelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.rl);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        animals = new String[]{};

        // Initialize an array list from array
        animalsList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(animals));

        // Define a layout for RecyclerView
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayout.VERTICAL,false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // Initialize a new instance of RecyclerView Adapter instance
        mAdapter = new AnimalsAdapter(mContext,animalsList);

        // Set the adapter for RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams alparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        atv = new TextView(this);
        atv.setLayoutParams(alparams);
        atv.setText("Currently no 'Device' is added, tap '+' to configure and add new 'Device'.");
        atv.setTextSize(19);
        atv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        atv.setPadding(70, 470, 70, 50);
        ahomeLayout.addView(atv);

        toolbar = new Toolbar(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams toolBarParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 120);
        toolbar.setLayoutParams(toolBarParams);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2fffffff"));
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        add_dev = new Dialog(Lighting.this);
        add_dev.setContentView(R.layout.add_device);
        v1 = View.inflate(this, R.layout.add_device, null);
        add_dev.setContentView(v1);

        dev_name1 = v1.findViewById(R.id.dev_name);
        dev_id1 = v1.findViewById(R.id.dev_id);
        dev_but1 = v1.findViewById(R.id.deviceBut1);

        dev_but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(dev_name1.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please input Home name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if(dev_id1.getText().toString().trim().length()<=0)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please input Device ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                    ahomeLayout.removeView(atv);
                    // String itemLabel = dev_name1.getText().toString().trim();

                    // Add an item to animals list
                    animalsList.add(position, "" + dev_name1.getText().toString());

                    // Scroll to newly added item position
                    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);

                    // Show the added item label
                    // Toast.makeText(mContext, "Added : " + itemLabel, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    names[mCount] = dev_name1.getText().toString().trim();
                    ids[mCount] = dev_id1.getText().toString().trim();
                    mCount++;
                    saveInPref();
                    add_dev.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        final Dialog alert = new Dialog(this);

        wv1 = new WebView(this);
        wv1.loadUrl("http:\\192.168.23.1");
        wv1.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        wv1.requestFocusFromTouch();
        wv1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void cardview2()
    {
        ahomeLayout.removeView(atv);
        mSettings2 = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFERENCES_2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        name = mSettings2.getString(name_key[j],"");

        animalsList.add(position, "" + name);
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
        j++;
    }

    public void saveInPref()
    {
        mSettings2 = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFERENCES_2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings2.edit();
        editor.putInt("COUNT_CARDS2", mCount);
        editor.putString(name_key[mCount-1],names[mCount-1]);
        editor.putString(id_key[mCount-1],ids[mCount-1]);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSettings2 = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFERENCES_2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings2.edit();
        editor.putInt("COUNT_CARDS2", mCount);
        if(mSettings2.contains("COUNT_CARDS2"))
        {
            mCount = mSettings2.getInt("COUNT_CARDS2", 0);
            for (int i=0; i<mCount; i++)
                cardview2();
        }
    }
```

Recyclerview Adapter class

```
public class AnimalsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AnimalsAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private List<String> mDataSet;
    private Context mContext;
    private Random mRandom = new Random();
    public SharedPreferences mSettings2;

    public AnimalsAdapter(Context context,List<String> list){
        mDataSet = list;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ImageButton mRemoveButton;
        public RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
        public ViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            mTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            mRemoveButton = v.findViewById(R.id.ib_remove);
            mRelativeLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.rl);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AnimalsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        // Create a new View
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.devices,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position){
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataSet.get(position));

        // Set a click listener for TextView
        holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String animal = mDataSet.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(mContext,animal,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Set a click listener for item remove button
        holder.mRemoveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Get the clicked item label
                String itemLabel = mDataSet.get(position);

                // Remove the item on remove/button click
                mDataSet.remove(position);

               /* Lighting remove = new Lighting();
                remove.mCount--;*/

                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mDataSet.size());

                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Removed : " + remove.mCount,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post some code snippets, without them we can't really help.

Comment: For editing sharing preference you just require context hence using any of the recycler view item context( itemView.getContext()), you can edit the preferences. for a concrete answer sharing the code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: Please refer to the code snippet now added.

Answer (score 0):

Use Interface to handle delete operation.

First create DeleteListener:

```
public interface DeleteListener {
    void onDelete(int position);
}
```

Then add listener to adapter as parameter and call it when click remove:

```
public AnimalsAdapter(Context context,List<String> list, DeleteListener listener){
    mDataSet = list;
    mListener = listener;
    mContext = context;
}

...

// Set a click listener for item remove button
    holder.mRemoveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Get the clicked item label
            String itemLabel = mDataSet.get(position);

            // Remove the item on remove/button click
            mDataSet.remove(position);

           /* Lighting remove = new Lighting();
            remove.mCount--;*/

            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mDataSet.size());

            mListener.onDelete(position);

            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Removed : " + remove.mCount,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

On your activity call adapter like this:

```
mAdapter = new AnimalsAdapter(mContext,animalsList, new DeleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDelete(int position) {

        }
    };);
```

Hope this helps.